# How to search a given JNDI in Weblogic console

Tags: java, jndi, weblogic11g

How can you search a given `JNDI` in weblogic console - to see where/how it is configured?

Answer (score 2):

[Viewing the JNDI Tree from Within the WebLogic Server Administration Console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jndi/jndi.html#477172)

You can monitor your deployments by viewing the JNDI tree from the WebLogic Server Administration Console. The JNDI tree will open in a separate browser window when you perform the following steps:

- Click the Servers node to expand it and expose the names of the
  servers currently being administered through the console.
- Click the name of the server whose JNDI tree you want to view.
- Scroll down to the bottom of the Configuration pane, and Click the
  "View JNDI Tree" link.
- The JNDI tree will appear in a new browser window. You can click on
  an individual object name to view information about its bind name and
  hash code.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jndi/jndi.html#477172

Comment: I was interested in a more like search form, as I do not know where a certain jndi is used and I want to find out. I do not want to take a look at each server to see which one is good.